# Session variables in PHP not appearing

Tags: php, session

I have read all the questions concerning this but I'm still at a loss.
Using a test script like this

```
// PAGE 1
<?php session_start();
echo var_dump($_SESSION) . "<br>";
$_SESSION[‘session_var’] = "stuff";
$PHPSESSID = session_id();
echo session_id() . "<br>";
?>
<html>
<head><title>Testing Sessions page 1</title></head> <body>
<p>This is a test of the sessions feature.
<form action="sessionTest2.php" method="POST"> 
<input type= "text" name= "form_var" value= "testing"> 
<input type= "submit" value= "Go to Next Page"> </form>
</body>
</html>

//PAGE 2
<?PHP session_start(); 
echo var_dump($_SESSION);
$session_var = $_SESSION['session_var']; 
$form_var = $_POST['form_var'];
echo "session_var =" . $session_var. "</br>"; 
echo "form_var =" . $form_var. "<br>";
$PHPSESSID = session_id();
echo session_id(); 
?>
```

the results I get in page 2 are

```
array(1) { ["‘session_var’"]=> string(5) "stuff" } session_var =
form_var =testing
al89u6vu02lstp99cs4damdn04
```

As you can see the variable session_var can be seen in the array but is not being output to the screen where expected, and yes session_start() is at the very top of both pages.

Any ideas what may be wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION[‘session_var’] = "stuff";
```

Is using non ascii `‘’` quote marks.

Are you using a word processor to edit your code?

Those quotes are now part of the key name, see this `["‘session_var’"]`.

Stick to simple ascii single and double quotes `'` or `"`